# How to create a button that has a circle attached to its left border?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button using html and css , the button is rectangular to three sides and on the right side there is a circular section attached to it and the buttons border goes around it.

Here is the image of button I'm trying to create:

[image]

My code so far:

```css
#GetOTPBlock {
   display: flex;
   width: fit-content; 
   padding: 8px
}
.get-otp {
   font-size: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: solid 2px #849dad;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #747f86;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 333;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="GetOTPBlock">
  <span class="get-otp">OR</span>
  <div id="GetOTPBlockAction">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Get OTP">Get OTP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you past the code you have so far?

Comment: sure, i posted the code.

Comment: I'd do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dbcov2et/
EDIT: Oh, I just saw your code now.

Comment: If the circle is just a visual clue then use CSS rather than HTML to create it. You an add a pseudo before or after element to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as below, by placing absolutely `get-otp` around `GetOTPBlock`. Feel free to adjust it to your need.

```css
#GetOTPBlock{
  position:relative;
  margin:1rem;
}

#GetOTPBlock .get-otp{
  position:absolute;
  width:2rem;
  height:2rem;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  left:-1rem;
  background-color: white;
  color: #849dad;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  border: 2px solid #849dad;
  border-radius:50%;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#GetOTPBlock a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:1rem 2rem;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#849dad;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="GetOTPBlock">
  <span class="get-otp">OR</span>
  <div id="GetOTPBlockAction">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Get OTP">Get OTP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you can change your HTML structure, you could make it simpler, using a pseudo element:

```css
#GetOTPBlockAction{
  position:relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #849dad;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin:1rem;
}

#GetOTPBlockAction::before {
  content:"Or";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: -1rem;
  background-color: white;
  color: #849dad;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #849dad;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;

}
```

```html
<a id="GetOTPBlockAction" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Get OTP">Get OTP</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a circle, use `position: absolute` on the circle while using `position: relative` on the button itself to position the circle relatively to the button. `top: 0` moves it to the top, `left: 0` moves it all the way to the left, so use them in correlation with the size of your button.

I'd suggest just using `box-shadow` to generate a "duplicate" circle which will be below the original circle, thus making it look like it has some kind of border.

```css
.main-btn {
  all: unset; /* Reset basic styling */
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative; /* Makes the circle position relatively to the button */
}

.circle {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 10px; /* Half of the circle's height */
  left: -5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 1.5px red; /* "Duplicate" the circle with red color */
}
```

```html
<button class="main-btn">
<div class="circle"></div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `::before` in your css like this

```css
.otp_button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(71, 73, 111);
    color: #fff;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;

}
.otp_button::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "or";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    left: -10px;
    background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
    font-size: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="otp_button">Get OTP</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).